# How to Position "MediaElement" media player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in web development, I am using MediaElement as my media player in my website. I'm trying to position the audio player but there are too many elements that need to be positioned separately. Is there an easy, singular approach to position the whole thing at once?

Comment: Please edit your answer to show your work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://mediaelementjs.com/#howitworks

Comment: this is the source website .. see the example you'll now what im trying to say

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some code snippets to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a parent element that surrounds just about any component in a web page, especially media players. That's the only thing that needs to be positioned; All child elements will follow.

Below I've created a running example of a **fake** media player. Notice only the top level `.player` class has positioning styles. Those are the only ones you need to set. All the child element styles would come from whatever default stylesheet comes with the media player itself.

```css
/* only position the parent container */
.player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

/* IGNORE THESE, assume they're from the media player's own stylesheets */
.player .player-video {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.player .player-controls {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #CCC;
}

.player .player-play-button,
.player .player-next-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
   <video class="player-video"></video>

   <div class="player-controls">
     <button class="player-play-button">PLAY</button>
     <button class="player-next-button">NEXT</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are other ways to position elements such as margins, padding and centering, so be sure to explore all options to make sure it'll layout correctly.

Comment: I think this is exactly what i needed to know , thanks Soviut

Answer (score 0):

One singular (but cheap) approach is to wrap your elements in a `<center>` tag, but I wouldn't seriously recommend this. If you're new to web development, you should at least be aware of it.

Other options primarily involve CSS. I would check out the [flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). It's fantastic for layouts.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Wrapping your items in a `<div>` with a class of `wrapper` will horizontally center the items within itself. If you're developing for platforms that support flexbox, then knowing flexbox layouts is helpful to avoid learning arcane, classic CSS hacks of horizontally centering elements.